# How to get conversation from guidance

Tags: chatgpt-api, large-language-model, gpt-4

I want to continue chatting with model (gpt-4 in my case) after the [guidance](https://github.com/guidance-ai/guidance) program is executed.
Example:

```py
experts = guidance('''
{{#system~}}
You are a helpful and terse assistant.
{{~/system}}

{{#user~}}
I want a response to the following question:
{{query}}
Name 3 world-class experts (past or present) who would be great at answering this?
Don't answer the question yet.
{{~/user}}

{{#assistant~}}
{{gen 'expert_names' temperature=0 max_tokens=300}}
{{~/assistant}}

{{#user~}}
Great, now please answer the question as if these experts had collaborated in writing a joint anonymous answer.
{{~/user}}

{{#assistant~}}
{{gen 'answer' temperature=0 max_tokens=500}}
{{~/assistant}}''')
experts(query='How can I be more productive?', caching=False)
```

outputs:

```
**system**
You are a helpful and terse assistant.
**user**
I want a response to the following question:
How can I be more productive?
Name 3 world-class experts (past or present) who would be great at answering this?
Don't answer the question yet.
**assistant**
1. Tim Ferriss
2. David Allen
3. Stephen Covey
**user**
Great, now please answer the question as if these experts had collaborated in writing a joint anonymous answer.
**assistant**
To be more productive:

1. Prioritize tasks using the Eisenhower Matrix, focusing on important and urgent tasks first.
2. Implement the Pomodoro Technique, breaking work into focused intervals with short breaks.
3. Continuously improve time management and organization skills by following the principles of David Allen's "Getting Things Done" method.
```

And after that I want to continue conversation with exact same dialogue. How can I achieve this?